# In a Spring MVC Hibernate Application , image path is getting changed from jsp to controller class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

In a Spring MVC hibernate app , I am selecting image from JSP and sending it to controller , but image path is getting changed because of this I am getting file not found error...
**This is my jsp code :**

> ```
>  <form name="reguserform">
>     <input type="file" name="userImage" id="userImage"/>
>  </form>
> ```

here I am selecting image from D: drive **D:\25986.jpeg**

**and below is my controller class code :**

```
 public String regUser(@RequestParam("userImage") File userImage) {
    System.out.println("Image  =  "+ userImage);
  }
```

// here i am getting : **Image  =  C:\fakepath\25986.jpeg**

because of this I cannot procced.
I dont know why image path is getting changed automatically. should I change the Input type for image ?  could somebody help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose it did what you want, and suppose I use your webapp, and choose to upload an image from my `K:\Documents\JBNizet` directory. You would thus get `K:\Documents\JBNizet\someImage.jpg` as argument to your method. What would it be useful for? A file path on the end-user's machine (my machine) doesn't represent anything meaningful on the webapp server (your machine).

Read [Spring MVC's documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc-multipart) to understand how you must handle file uploads.